# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Posting a Form Back to the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm trying to create a basic form with an image button that posts data back to the controller. My form looks like the following:

**MyView.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBox("queryTextBox", string.Empty, new { style = "width:150px;" })
  <input type="image" alt="Search" src="/img/search.png" value="Search" name="ExecuteQuery" />
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    ViewData["CurrentDate"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
    return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ExecuteQuery()
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      return View();
    }
  }
}
```

I have verified that I'm accessing my controller code. The way I've been able to do this is by successfully printing out the "CurrentDate" associated with the ViewData. However, when I click my image button, I was assuming that my break point in the ExecuteQuery method would fire. It does not. What am I doing wrong? How do I do a simple POST in MVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form is pointing to the wrong action.

Calling `Html.BeginForm()` creates a `<form>` that POSTs to the current action (`Index`).
You need to pass the action name to `BeginForm`.

Comment: Even if I use "@using (Html.BeginForm("ExecuteQuery", null))" it still does not work. What could it be?

Comment: You also need to pass the controller name.

Comment: I've tried it with both "@using (Html.BeginForm("ExecuteQuery", "My"))" and "@using (Html.BeginForm("ExecuteQuery", "MyController"))" without any luck. What could it be?

Comment: Check the URLs in Fiddler or Firebug and figure where it's going.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExecuteQuery", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBox("queryTextBox", string.Empty, new { style = "width:150px;" })
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

In your controller

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     ViewData["CurrentDate"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
     return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ExecuteQuery(string queryTextBox)
  {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         // DO SOMETHING WITH queryTextBox
         return View();
     }
  }
}
```

If the image submit button is very important for you, you can still change the button background image using CSS.